# Major and minor path / components with Oracle NoSQL

Tags: java, oracle, nosql

I am not sure why with Oracle NoSQL there is a `List` of String major and minor components like this code:

```
List<String> majorComponents = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> minorLength = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> minorYear = new ArrayList<String>();

majorComponents.add(“Katana”);
minorLength .add(“length”);
minorYear.add(“year”);

Key key1 = Key.createKey(majorComponents, minorLength);
Key key2 = Key.createKey(majorComponents, minorYear);

String valString = "sword";

store.putIfAbsent(key1, Value.createValue(valString.getBytes()));
store.putIfAbsent(key2, Value.createValue(valString.getBytes()));
```

And I am also not sure what is the difference of `components` to `path`?

Can someone explain how this major and minor paths are in a List and how does it really work.

Can I assume that for key1, when I get the full path here's what I get:

```
Katana:length
```

For key2

```
Katana:year
```

If I put:

```
majorComponents.add(“Saber”);
```

and then do:

```
Key key1 = Key.createKey(majorComponents, minorLength);
```

What will happen? What will be the full path? I'm quite confused as to how this really works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the canonical path by doing a toString() on the Key after you create it. It will show you each of the components of the major and minor portions. Take a look at the oracle.kv.Key javadoc for details.

Charles Lamb